# Scikit Random Forest Classifier does not evaluate to True

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Curious edge behavior. In this example, `KNN exists` gets printed, but `Random Forest exists` does not.

Discovered it when checking for the presence of a model, where `if model: ...` was not triggered when the model is a Random Forest.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

if KNeighborsClassifier(4):
    print('KNN exists')

if RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, max_depth=4):
    print('Random Forest exists')
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: weiiiird. This could be a consequence of `RandomForestClassifier` implementing `__len__`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha! It's because `Random` implements `__len__`:

```
In [1]: from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
   ...: from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
   ...:

In [2]: knn =  KNeighborsClassifier(4)

In [3]: forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, max_depth=4)

In [4]: knn.__bool__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ef1cfe16be77> in <module>()
----> 1 knn.__bool__

AttributeError: 'KNeighborsClassifier' object has no attribute '__bool__'

In [5]: knn.__len__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-dc98bf8c50e0> in <module>()
----> 1 knn.__len__

AttributeError: 'KNeighborsClassifier' object has no attribute '__len__'

In [6]: forest.__bool__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-fbdd7f01e843> in <module>()
----> 1 forest.__bool__

AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute '__bool__'

In [7]: forest.__len__
Out[7]:
<bound method BaseEnsemble.__len__ of RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=4, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
            verbose=0, warm_start=False)>

In [8]: len(forest)
Out[8]: 0
```

And, according to the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__):

> `object.__bool__(self)`
>
> Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation
>   `bool()`; should return False or True. When this method is not defined,
>   `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, **and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero.** If a class defines neither `__len__()`
>   nor `__bool__()`, all its instances are considered true.

As one might expect, the `len` of a `RandomForestClassifier` is the number of estimators, but only *after* it is `.fit`:

```
In [9]: from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
   ...: X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
   ...:             n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
   ...:             random_state=0, shuffle=False)
   ...:

In [10]: X.shape
Out[10]: (1000, 4)

In [11]: y.shape
Out[11]: (1000,)

In [12]: forest.fit(X,y)
Out[12]:
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=4, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
            verbose=0, warm_start=False)

In [13]: len(forest)
Out[13]: 10
```